# Swift: Xcode 7.3.1 install an iOS app into a device without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code

I have built an app via Xcode 7.3.1. I could install it using Xcode with an apple account (Not an iOS developer).

However, if some people want to use my app, they need to connect to my Mac or install Xcode on their own Mac. I want to package my app as an application so they could download from somewhere.

I have seen some people post their app online and use a QR code for downloading. How to let others download it and install it to the device without uploading to the Apple Store or using Xcode? Thanks in advance for any other solutions.

Comment: If you have paid developer membership then you can either obtain the UDIDs, add these to your provisioning profile and distribute an ad-hoc build to them, or you can use TestFlight

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not a developer membership and my host company does not provide any budget for the app. I am an intern without any pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not own developer membership, you can't install your app to real device without Xcode.

To install you app to a real device without Xcode, first off all you need to [export](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) your app to an ipa file (To do so, you need an developer account).

Then 
if you have right to access iTunes Connect

you can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

else

you can use something like [TestFairy](https://free.testfairy.com/) ..